# making multiple criteria search for php sql

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a website that have function for searching with multiple criteria in checkbox and option. The search function will work without a post button for sent the variable so maybe i think it will use the javascript also. My hope the searching function will be like this image below, that added sub url

[image]

Anyway this is my code but it not finish yet and not working well. I just confusion and need some help for my project. Thx for helping before.

my sql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY id DESC";
$sort = ($_GET['sort']);
{
if ($sort == 1) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY harga ASC";
}
if ($sort == 2) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY harga DESC";
}}
```

javascript

```
<script>
        function sortt(){
        document.getElementById('sorttt').submit(); 
        }   
    </script>
    <script>
        function jeniss(){
        document.getElementById('jenisss').submit();    
        }   
    </script>
    <script>
        function kategorii(){
        document.getElementById('kategoriii').submit(); 
        }   
    </script>
```

html

```
<form id="jenisss" >
<div class="sidebar-list" name="jenis" onclick="jeniss();">                             
<ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="1a"> <a> Kos  </a> </li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="1b"> <a> Kontrakan </a> </li>                                    
</ul>
</div>
</form>

<form id="kategoriii" >
<div class="sidebar-list" name="kategori" onclick="kategorii();">
     <ul>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="2a"> <a> Khusus Pria </a> </li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="2b"> <a> Khusus Wanita </a> </li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="2c"> <a> Campuran </a> </li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="2d"> <a> 2 Lantai </a> </li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" value="2e"> <a> 3 Lantai </a> </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="2f"> <a> 4 Lantai atau Lebih </a> </li>
     </ul>
</div>
</form>

<form id="sorttt" >
<label>Urut Berdasarkan : </label>
<select name="sort" onchange="sortt();">
<option style="display:none;">------Pilih Disini------</option>
<option value="1" <?php if ($_GET['sort'] == 1) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> >Harga Terendah</option>
<option value="2" <?php if ($_GET['sort'] == 2) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> >Harga Tertinggi</option>

 </select>
</form>
```

Srry for the messy code and thank for helping.

Comment: to begin with, just use one form instead of several different ones. Then you can submit all the values together at the same time. Then, in your server, read all the possible values, check them and use them to gradually construct a SQL query which will represent all the criteria. Beware of SQL injection vulnerabilities in the process.

Comment: You also have a few other little problems - none of your form elements have "name" attributes, so their values will never be submitted to the server. And you need to have a single "Submit" button so you can wait for the user to choose all their criteria and then click to initiate the search (rather than submitting as soon as they choose one thing).

Comment: @ADyson i try to make live search that no need submit button, thats why i create the javascript. Every action will be sent to server whenever the user check or unchecked the checkbox or choose the option.

Comment: ok sure well you can do it like that, but you still need one single form containing all the fields, so that the current values for all the fields can be submitted together.